# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start not work with IIS, but on ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS2008 C# and testing on my local XP Pro PC with local IIS, I have wrote a web service to call a third party software .exe file to use svn checkout commands to insert data into a folder, which use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start . The same codes did work when I use VS2008 build-in ASP.NET Development Server(http://localhost:2999/MyServices/MyServices.asmx). but when I use IIS normal URL(http://developer/MyServices/MyServices.asmx) to run Process.Start on the web service, it just haunlted and not doing anything.plz send one sample program.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely down to the user being used to run the code. When using the built-in server, it is running as the same user as Visual Studio is running as. When in IIS, it will be running as the MACHINENAME\ASPNET user.

If the process you are starting cannot execute as the MACHINENAME\ASPNET user, it will not work when hosted in IIS unless you change your configuration to change the user it runs as. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302377.aspx) page for more info on what users are used for what in IIS.

Comment: Thank you for answer, 
but i changed <identity impersonate="true"/> then also it won' work. and i don't know how to use HttpContext Windows Identity Thread variable,
please explain with example its my humble request to you.

Comment: @subbu, you really need to learn more about ASP.NET impersonation. If right now anonymous access is enabled for your web application, then IUSR account is used to execute the exe, and it of course fails if this exe requires more permissions.

Comment: so how to give less permission to IUSR machine account, rite now am using XP.